# Adding two outputs together

Tags: javascript, html

I got a profit calculator from a developer, which works perfectly, and I want to add the final result with the amount which has been typed in.

This is my code:

```js
//////////PROFIT CALCULATOR

const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
const resultText = document.querySelector(".result");
let value, percent; // must be declared outside of the foreach

numbers.forEach((number) => {
  number.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (number.classList.contains("value")) {
      value = parseFloat(number.value);
    }

    if (number.classList.contains("percent")) {
      percent = parseFloat(number.value);
    }

    if ((value || value == 0) && (percent || percent == 0)) {
      resultText.innerHTML = calculate(value, percent);
    }
  });
});

function calculate(val, percent) {
  return (val * percent) / 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="percentage-calc">
  <div class="input_container">
    <span>Amount</span>
    <input type="number" class="number value">$
  </div>
  <div class="input_container">
    <span>Percent</span>
    <input type="number" class="number percent">% = $
    <span class="result"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please I need help

Comment: So you just want to add the input value to the calculated percentage? `resultText.innerHTML = value + calculate(value, percent);`

Comment: Or, if you _always_ want to calculate `X plus Y percent of X`, instead of just `Y percent of X`, you can of course also implement it _inside_ the `calculate` function as well -  `return val + (val * percent) / 100;`

Comment: If `value || value == 0` is just there to check for `NaN`, you could make it a little clearer and use `isNaN()` instead. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to add the result to the typed Amount.

Add the **value** to your calculate function :

```
function calculate(val, percent) {
    return (val * percent) / 100 + value;
}
```